# What function does ethereum mist wallet use to send custom tokens?

Tags: solidity, mist

I have created my own currency(advancedToken) - `ABC` using the code given at
https://www.ethereum.org/token#full-coin-code

I have understood the transfer of coin using the contract function `Transfer`: It calls the transfer function in the code and executes it for the parameters.[image: Sending amount by contract function]

But in the `send` tab of ethereum mist wallet, I can send my tokens - `ABCs` to another account just like I can send ethers.[image]

What part of code enabled this ? What function of contract is called when `ABCs` are send ?

Answer (score 7):

The wallet uses the Transfer() function, just like you'd do by calling the contract directly. But we designed the interface so you don't see the difference between tokens and ether transfers.

Comment: What I am doing in the contract is just changing values in mapping. How your inbuilt function Transfer() is called?